# 2D vector error c++ recursion

Tags: c++, memory, twitter, vector

I have this code which I wrote to calculate the degrees of separation between two users on twitter. The error I'm getting happens on the second iteration of my third for loop. When it gets to `IdList.push_back(myIDs2["ids"][l].GetInt());`

When it hits this point it exits the program with code 0x3. Am I right in assuming the way I'm reading into and interating through my vectors is causing memory issues?

Here is the code

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> separationStages(6);
std::vector<int> IdList;
std::vector<std::string> stringIdList;
std::string response;
std::string nextCursor = "";
std::string previousCursor = "";
int degreesOfSeparation = 0;
//request my ids
twitterobj.friendsIdsGet(nextCursor, myScreenName, false);
twitterobj.getLastWebResponse(response);
//if the response doesnt contain an error
    if (!errorCheck(response))
    {
        std::cout << "There has been an error. " <<response << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
            Document myIDs;
            myIDs.Parse(response.c_str());
            myIDs.IsObject();
            myIDs.HasMember("ids");
            myIDs["ids"].IsArray();
            //for how many ids in the response set each of those into separation vector
            for (size_t i = 0; i < myIDs["ids"].Size(); i++)
            {
                std::string temp = "";
                myIDs["ids"][i].IsInt();
                IdList.push_back(myIDs["ids"][i].GetInt());
                temp = std::to_string(IdList[i]);
                separationStages[0].push_back(temp);
            }

            IdList.clear();
            //checking how many ids in first degree
            std::cout << separationStages[0].size() << std::endl;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < separationStages[0].size(); j++)
            {
                if (separationStages[0][j] == degreeSearch)
                {
                    degreesOfSeparation = 1;
                    return degreesOfSeparation;
                }
            }

            for (size_t k = 0; k < separationStages[0].size(); k++)
            {
                std::cout << "Checking friend number " << k + 1 << " in first degree" << std::endl;
                Sleep(60000);
                //get that users friend list
                twitterobj.friendsIdsGet(nextCursor, separationStages[0][k], true);
                twitterobj.getLastWebResponse(response);
                if (!errorCheck(response))
                {
                    std::cout << "error at start of second degree" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    Document myIDs2;
                    myIDs2.Parse(response.c_str());
                    myIDs2.IsObject();
                    myIDs2.HasMember("ids");
                    myIDs2["ids"].IsArray();
                    for (size_t l = 0; l < myIDs2["ids"].Size(); l++)
                    {
                        std::string temp = "";
                        myIDs2["ids"][l].IsInt();
                        IdList.push_back(myIDs2["ids"][l].GetInt());
                        temp = std::to_string(IdList[l]);
                        separationStages[1].push_back(temp);
                    }
                    IdList.clear();
                    std::cout << "Size of separationStages[1] = " << separationStages[1].size() << std::endl;

                    for (size_t m = 0; m < separationStages[1].size(); m++)
                    {
                        if (separationStages[1][m] == degreeSearch)
                        {
                            degreesOfSeparation = 2;
                            return degreesOfSeparation;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return degreesOfSeparation;
```

Comment: You might want to reduce your code to a minimal working example. Also, have you tried using a debugger before that line?

Comment: @AlexanderBüse No one will be able to compile it unless they build and install several libraries. What do you mean by a debugger through?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) for a debugger explanation. It would allow you to step through your code and inspect variable values to check that everything is working as you expect it

Comment: You didn't read my question. I already told you what lime it happens